# Why /dev/disk/by-id/ change after a suddenly server power-off?

Tags: hard-drive, fstab, udev, partitioning, uuid

I'm management a server that in `/etc/fstab` have references to some partitions using `/dev/disk/by-id/DISK_ID-partN`.

The server suddenly power-off and DISK_ID part of `/dev/disk/by-id/DISK_ID-partN` changed.

I always refer partition in `/etc/fstab` using *UUID* and will change the conf of *fstab*, but still I want know why the *by-id* change when tons of people on Internet said that such hard disk identifier don't change, even I read that OpenSuse use *by-id* in tis *fstab*.

Can partitions *UUID*s change too after a suddenly power-off? are *UUID*s less "mutable" than *by-id*s? I think that an explanation from where *by-id* come will help me to understand all this. I read that UUID is stored in the partition and just change its value  after partition formatting, but not know much about *by-id*, just that *udev* is who generated-create it, but basing in what?

Comment: What did it change from/to?  The disk-id is normally taken from the disk hardware, so it won't change unless you physically replace the disk.

Comment: @psusi I don't replace the disk between reboots. Those references are in *fstab* since months. I don't have now access to the server, but I don't think that old/new (from/to) values are relevant to my question. Anyway I could find new and old *by-id* values if you think could help to find out what happen. Anyway, someone that know *udev* deep enough could explain that ;) Thanks again for your comment.

Comment: @gsi-frank, I could find trace in doc that uuid detected by libblkid > blkid > udev . Most talk only about uuid of partition which most linux fs have it stored in its meta. I couldn't find any which mentions the uuid of disk node itself. Could it be BIOS/UEFI which boots differently? I haven't seen something like this.

Answer (score 1):

gsc-frank!

I am assuming the content of the partitions is still there and the UUID is the same.

Someone cloned the contents of the disk to a new one and replaced the disk.

[UUIDs don't change when you duplicate a disk with dd (unlike disk/by-id) . They only change when you format a partition.](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/install-boot-login/450292-clonning-hard-disk-disk-id-problem.html) [post number 3 in the linked discussion]

The disk might have been replaced due to several possible reasons:

- SMART values have been deteriorating and to prevent loss of data on the respective disk it was cloned and replaced
- disk was filling up and was replaced by a bigger one with same partition layout
- disk was replaced due to speed reasons, e.g. HDD --> SSD
- disk was replaced to obtain the original disk with it's data - for example as backup or evidence - but leave the system running.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu Tobias. Pls, allays read carefully the questions before reply. The disk was never replaced, the only event was a **suddenly server power-off** as I said in my question. I also stated in my question: "I read that UUID is stored in the partition and just change its value after partition formatting", so, seem to me that you don't ready my question at all.